# Use of undefined constant name assumed 'title' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Tags: php, html

I was following tutorials but this error is showing for this line. I am confused about what to do? It's saying it will give an error in the near future. I used this for the nav bar.

```
 $navItems = array(
                      array(
                           slug => "index.php",
                           title => "Home",
                      ),
                        array(
                           slug => "about.php",
                           title => "About Us",
                        ),
                        array(
                            slug => "timetable.php",
                            title => "Timetable",
                        ),
        
                        array(
                            slug => "appointment.php",
                            title => "Appointment",
                        ),
```

[image]

Comment: It should be “title”=>”...” so also the key should have the double quote

Comment: Thanks a lot ...worked like a charm ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array keys should be enclosed within double quotes, like this

```
array(
  "name" => "John"
)
```

The error you're getting means PHP will assume you meant to use `"title"` so it works with backwards compatibility, but this feature will be removed in the future.